# Label foreign key lines on schema for sqlite db?

Tags: schemacrawler

I'm generating a schema diagram against a sqlite3 database using schemacrawler. The foreign key relationship lines all have some sort of arbitrary alphanumeric string label on them, like SC_8D200EE2_9FA6C015.

[image: sqliteschema]

I would like to explicitly label some of these lines myself, and remove the label altogether from other lines. Can I achieve this entirely by manipulating the database before running schemacrawler against it? Or do I have to generate a dot file for graphviz and then manipulate that before rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These names are generated by SchemaCrawler, but they can be suppressed using configuration options. If you want to customize the names, you will need to edit the generated DOT file, before rendering using Graphviz. Please use the SchemaCrawler `scdot` output format.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: The is functionality is available in SchemaCrawler 16.16.18 onwards - see https://www.schemacrawler.com/attributes.html